# Subset of python list based on groups of elements of same list, pythonically

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a **flat** list of numbers that are **logically** in groups of 3, where each triple is (number, __ignored, flag[0 or 1]), eg:

`[7,56,1, 8,0,0, 2,0,0, 6,1,1, 7,2,0, 2,99,1]`

I would like to (pythonically) process this list to create a new list of numbers based on the value of 'flag': if 'flag' is 1, then I want 'number', else 0. So the above list would become:

`[7, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2]`

My initial attempt at doing this is:

```
list = [7,56,1, 8,0,0, 2,0,0, 6,1,1, 7,2,0, 2,99,1]
numbers = list[::3]
flags = list[2::3]

result = []
for i,number in enumerate(numbers):
  result.append(number if flags[i] == 1 else 0)
```

This works, but it seems to me that there should be a better way to extract tuples cleanly from a list. Something like:

```
list = [7,56,1, 8,0,0, 2,0,0, 6,1,1, 7,2,0, 2,99,1]
for (number, __, flag) in list:
    ...etc
```

But I don't seem to be able to do this.

I could just loop through the entire list:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    result.append(list[i] if list[i+2] == 1 else 0)
```

Which seems smaller and more efficient.

I am unclear about the best option here. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Note:** I have accepted the answer by wim:

`[L[i]*L[i+2] for i in range(0, len(L), 3)]`

But want to reiterate that both wims and ShadowRangers responses work. I accepted wim's answer based on simplicity and clarity (and, to a lesser extent, compatibility with python 2, though ShadowRanger pointed out that zip was in Py2 as well, so this basis is invalid).

The answer by ShadowRanger:

`[number if flag else 0 for number, _, flag in zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3)]`

also does exactly what I thought I wanted (providing tuples), but is a little obscure and requires zip. As wim noted, ShadowRanger's answer would be very well suited to a stream of data rather than a fixed list.

I would also note that ShadowRanger's answer adds obscure use of zip() (which will become less obscure with time), but adds clarity by the use of named values for the tuple, so it's a bit of a win/lose.

For those struggling to understand `zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3)]`, it creates three copies of the one iterator, which are then used to contruct tuples. Because it's the same iterator, each use advances the iterator, making the tuples exactly as I requested.

For both clarity and generality, I am also somewhat inclined to a modified version of the solution from @ShadowRanger:

```
i = iter(mylist)
[number if flag else 0 for number, _, flag in zip(i, i, i)]
```

(which, to me, seems much less obscure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most direct way would be a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [L[i]*L[i+2] for i in range(0, len(L), 3)]
[7, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2]
```

Or consider numpy, it's powerful for tasks like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(L).reshape(-1, 3).T
>>> a
array([[ 7,  8,  2,  6,  7,  2],
       [56,  0,  0,  1,  2, 99],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1]])
>>> a[0]*a[2]
array([7, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2])
```

Comment: Both of those look pretty solid -- though I did oversimplify, the flag field is a text field, so multiplication is not an option. But the basic solutions you suggest work in the more general case I think. Thank you!

Comment: As a side-issue, given it can be done is a basic list through your first option, am I correct in assuming restructuring the array with numpy would be considerably less efficient?

Comment: Not necessarily - numpy is usually much more efficient that Python loops for bigger data. But if you have a mix of text and numbers, then numpy is probably not a great choice - you would want to pre-process to turn the textual flags into numeric flags in order to get the efficiency gains of using numpy arrays.

Comment: Note: I accepted this answer based on simplicity and clarity (and, to a lesser extent, compatibility with python 2). The answer by @ShadowRanger is also great; it does exactly what I thought I wanted (providing tuples), but is a little obscure and requires zip. As wim noted, the latter would be very well suited to a stream of data rather than a fixed list.

Comment: @RabidMutant: Not objecting to accepting this one, but a note: My answer works just fine with Python 2. It works more efficiently in Py2 if you add a conditional import of `from itertools import izip as zip` (so you get a lazy, Py3-style `zip` even in Py2), or `izip_longest as zip_longest` if you went that route, but it works with plain `zip` on Py2 (`zip` has been around forever, only change from Py2 to Py3 is that Py2 version produced `list` of `tuple`s, Py3 version produces iterator of `tuple`s).

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the clarification and correction; I really like your solution, in many ways it seems more elegant (and certainly more generalizable). The only qualm I really have is the hieroglyphic (C-like) nature of the zip construct. For a python-person, I imagine it might be second nature, but for me the list-based solution looked more accessible. Your solution is much closer to what I see as the ideal "for a,b,c in <list>", and I am sure I will use it in the future. Of course, I am only new to python so my judgement is likely flawed! I really wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have logical triples, you can use a little hack with `iter`, sequence multiplication and `zip` to accomplish your goal:

```
result = []
for number, _, flag in zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3):
    result.append(number if flag else 0)  # flag is only 1 or 0, so no need to compare it
```

That unpacks the *same* iterator over `mylist` as three arguments to `zip`; since it's the same iterator, `zip` pulls element 0, 1 and 2 for the first output, then 3, 4 and 5, etc. Your loop then unpacks the three elements to logical names (using `_` for the value you don't care about).

A list comprehension could even one-line it to:

```
result = [number if flag else 0 for number, _, flag in zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3)]
```

though that's getting a little dense, meaning-wise.

Advantages to this approach are:

1. It works with *any* iterable, not just `list`s
2. It's performant; the input is traversed exactly once, where any slicing solution would traverse it multiple times
3. It uses meaningful names, not anonymous magic numbers for index offsets

Downside:

1. `zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3)` is a little magical
2. It will silently omit data if your input turns out to not have a length that's a multiple of three (the partial group at the end is dropped)

Note: In anything resembling production code, don't inline the `zip`/`iter`/unpack trick. Use [the `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (or a `zip`-based variant) and call that:

```
# Defined somewhere else for common use
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

for number, _, flag in grouper(mylist, 3):
```

The recipe is tested and predictable, and by giving it a name you make the code using it much more obvious.

Comment: I think your suggestion is significantly worse than OP's original code (needless sophistication/complication)

Comment: Great solution; and I do like what seem to be good performance implications of using zip. Now I wish I could accept both answers. They are both excellent.

Comment: @wim: In real code, I'd probably factor out the grouping following [the `itertools` `grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), so the magic is contained in code that's known to be vetted and "Python approved" without distracting from the code using it. It's strictly better performance-wise, but I agree without the refactoring it's obscure (I said as much in my "Downsides"). As I noted, it does have the unique advantage of iterating exactly once, making it work with arbitrary input iterables, including one-pass iterators.

Comment: @wim why is this worse than my code? The obscurity of zip? Or something else? [I admit I am still trying to understand it, which is probably a bad sign!]

Comment: Because you have an input *list*, which offers the nice feature of O(1) access by index. May as well take advantage of that feature. The zip and splat tricks are not readable.

Comment: Yes, I am drawn to the fact this does what I hoped for (an iterator providing triples), but the simplicity of just processing the list probably has to win out. Now I understand the zip code, I will ferret it away, but it's a bit too "side-effecty" for me. Cute tho!

Comment: @ShadowRanger in terms of readability, I would possibly be inclined to ```i= iter(list) \n result = [number if flag else 0 for number, _, flag in zip(i, i, i)]``` ; if you know the list had 3n elements, I'd also be really curious why you would not just use the zip code directly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RabidMutant: Using the `zip(*[iter(x)]*3)` trick requires understanding multiple somewhat obscure facets of Python, and if you don't understand even one of them, it's confusing as hell (and initially confusing no matter what). Hiding that complexity in a function with a useful name and descriptive docstring means you don't get slammed with that complexity when evaluating each bit of code using it, that's all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, but is my proposed solution of ```zip(i, i, i)``` not a sufficient work-around for that obscurity?

Comment: @RabidMutant: It works around most of it. It's still a little confusing to folks that don't understand explicit creation of iterators, and how `zip` can consume the same iterator as multiple arguments independently. And it's still going to take longer for a maintainer to grok than just using the `grouper` recipe.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the quick replies! The double-splat got me in the first instance; I like this format because it is fairly clear whats going on, and it gives names to the elements, which would be especially valuable in the general case (larger tuples, any iterator etc). Thanks again; I've learned a lot in this set of discussions!

Answer (score 2):

I guess this may work:

```
>>> list_ = [7,56,1, 8,0,0, 2,0,0, 6,1,1, 7,2,0, 2,99,1]
>>> [a if c == 1 else 0 for a,c in zip(list_[::3],list_[2::3])]
... 
 [7, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2]
```

Comment: I think this one loses out to the solution from @ShadowRanger because it uses two lists, whereas theirs uses two iterators.

Comment: End of my comment should read "...whereas theirs uses three copies of a single iterator."